# Using AQuery with Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, aquery

I need to use AQuery in my Android project, in order to do asynchronous calls to the server. I just want to call the server and when it will give me data, I'll update my view with these data.
So, I wrote the asynchronous call inside an AsyncTask. Below you can see what I did:

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView categorieListView ; 

    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapterCategorie ;
    private AQuery aq;
    private String[] lista = null;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String nome_categoria;
    private int[] arrayID = null;

    ArrayList<String> planetList;
    JsonRequestActivity categoryAjax;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        aq = new AQuery(this.getActivity(), view);                       
        categorieListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);        
        //new FetchMyDataTask(this.getActivity(), new FetchMyDataTaskCompleteListener(listAdapterCategorie, categorieListView, this.getActivity()), aq).execute("InputString");

        if(lista == null){
            new AggiornaLista().execute();
        }else{
            listAdapterCategorie = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.categoriegenerali, R.id.nomeAttivita, lista);
            categorieListView.setAdapter( listAdapterCategorie );
        }

        categorieListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        Intent esercizioScelto = new Intent(this.getActivity(), CategoriaScelta.class);
        nome_categoria = categorieListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        esercizioScelto.putExtra("nome_categoria", nome_categoria);
        esercizioScelto.putExtra("id_categoria", arrayID[position]);
        startActivity(esercizioScelto);   
    }             

    private class AggiornaLista extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog.setMessage("Caricamento dati server");                  
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = Const.URL_JSON_ARRAY;

            Map<String, String> params2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params2.put("type", "get_all");

            aq.ajax(url, params2, JSONArray.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONArray>() {                                                

                @Override
                public void callback(String url, JSONArray json, AjaxStatus status) {
                    if(json != null){
                        lista = new String[json.length()];
                        arrayID = new int[json.length()];
                        for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
                            try {
                                lista[i] = result.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name");
                                arrayID[i] = result.getJSONObject(i).getInt("ID");
                            } 
                            catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        //Toast.makeText(aq.getContext(), jsonArray.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{                              
                        //ajax error, show error code
                        //Toast.makeText(aq.getContext(), "Error:" + status.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    // do something with the result                             

                }
            });       
            return lista;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result[])
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            listAdapterCategorie = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.categoriegenerali, R.id.nomeAttivita, result);

            // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter. 
            categorieListView.setAdapter( listAdapterCategorie );

        }

    }

}
```

That implentation does not work as I expected. In fact, inside the onPostExecute, the parameter returned by the doInBackground is not updated and it contains the initialization value (null).
Then I changed something only in the AsyncTask:

```
private class AggiornaLista extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog.setMessage("Caricamento dati server");

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = Const.URL_JSON_ARRAY;

            Map<String, String> params2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params2.put("type", "get_all");

            aq.ajax(url, params2, JSONArray.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONArray>() {                                                
                @Override
                public void callback(String url, JSONArray json, AjaxStatus status) {
                    if(json != null){
                        lista = new String[json.length()];
                        arrayID = new int[json.length()];
                        for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
                            try {
                                lista[i] = result.getJSONObject(i).getString("Name");
                                arrayID[i] = result.getJSONObject(i).getInt("ID");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        //Toast.makeText(aq.getContext(), jsonArray.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{                              
                        //ajax error, show error code
                        //Toast.makeText(aq.getContext(), "Error:" + status.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    // do something with the result                             
                    listAdapterCategorie = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.categoriegenerali, R.id.nomeAttivita, lista);

                    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter. 
                    categorieListView.setAdapter( listAdapterCategorie );
                }
            });       
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

Doing that, the user inteface is correctly updated, but I think it's not the correct way to do that.
So, what can I do?
Thanks.

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you are currently wrapping an asynchronous task in an asynchronous task. Your `aq.ajax(...)` is starting a new thread to make the call and then invokes the `callback(...)` you defined.
The `AsyncTask` executes the `doInBackground()`, where you start another task. The `doInBackground()` method finishes, before your ajax call is done. So the `onPostExecute()` is executed before the ajax call is finished.

The solution would be to omit the whole AsyncTask structure. Just call your `aq.ajax()` in your main `onCreateView` and do what you have to do, when the call returns in the callback you defined. (Basically put the contents of your `doInBackGround()` in your main

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your reply. Following your suggestion, I created an example project: basically, it only has a text view showing a string value passed by the server. This is the main activity, the only one in the project:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private AQuery aq;
    private String serverParameter = "";
    private TextView myTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        aq = new AQuery(this);
        asyncCall();
        myTextView.setText(serverParameter);        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void asyncCall(){

        String url = "http://tryourweb.altervista.org/LocalOfferte0.0/src/category_controller.php";

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("type", "get_all");

        aq.ajax(url, params, JSONArray.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void callback(String url, JSONArray json, AjaxStatus status) {
                if(json != null){
                    //successful ajax call, show status code and json content
                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(aq.getContext(), status.getCode() + ":" + json.getJSONObject(0).getString("Name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        serverParameter = json.getJSONObject(0).getString("Name");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }else{  
                    //ajax error, show error code
                    Toast.makeText(aq.getContext(), "Error:" + status.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });     

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the setText sets the initialization value.
How can I solve that?
Thank you again.

Andrea

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I didn't get an alert, because you haven't wrote a comment to my answer. 

You have to set the text of your TextView again. 
`serverParameter = json.getJSONObject(0).getString("Name");

myTextView.setText(serverParameter);`